# "Internet explorer cannot display this webpage" - every other browser is fine

Tags: php, internet-explorer

On my site's forum (http://www.kanyetothe.com/forum/), when a user submits a post from IE, they receive the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", yet it works for every other browser. This is baffling. Does anybody have any ideas?

I set up a test account, user: testing / pass: test1 if you'd like to see for yourself.

Comment: Which versions of IE? Is there any authentication in place?

Comment: First, you should get rid of the XHTML-Strict. You're sending it as text/html anyway, so it's basically HTML3.2 with trailing garbage in some tags.

Comment: It happens at least in IE8, not sure about previous versions since I can't test right now. Mario: will that fix the problem?

Comment: Hmm... MSIE8 with no plugins or updates just worked for me. http://www.kanyetothe.com/forum/index.php?topic=1122.new#new Maybe it's related to a plugin/add-on for IE? Try disabling ActiveX/Silverlight/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried in MSIE4 - 8... not working in any of them (MSIE4-6 returns blank page, 7 and 8 returns the mentioned error)

I've also checked with Firebug and it seems that:

- a request to the following address, which returns error 400 is made on the page: http://www.kanyetothe.com/forum/%smileySource% - this probably won't solve the problem, as it's on multiple pages and the others work, just a thing worth fixing
- gzip compression is enabled on the server  - probably works fine, just a thing to have in mind when debugging

Furthermore, there are errors in the actual code - you have 2 closing tags for BODY and HTML at the end, and some HEAD data which are inserted after the HEAD section is actually being closed.

Can't say whether any of this will help you solve the mentioned problem but at least you have something to start with :)

Comment: When and how is that request being made?

Comment: I managed to fix the error. I have no idea what was causing it, but it was caused by the SMF forum system, in Sources/post.php

Comment: the request is being made directly after loading "/forum/Themes/default/scripts/editor.js?rc3" file, so I'd try to find that somewhere after this in code or in that JavaScript file itself